Sending a file from Android device to AWS S3 through server spring boot application
I want to send a mp4 file from android device to AWS S3 storage bucket through spring boot application on heroku server.
Which method I should use on my android app side to send the file?
I got following code on server side:
@RequestMapping("/add")
@Controller
public class AddProductController {

   @Autowired
   private FileService fileService;

   @GetMapping
   public ModelAndView add (){
      return getFormMAV(new Product());
   }

   @PostMapping
    public ModelAndView add(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, @Valid Product product, BindingResult bindingResult){
        LOG.info("File received {}", file);
        LOG.info("Product received {}", product);

        if (bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            if (file.isEmpty()){
                bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("product", "imagePath", "Plik nie moze byc pusty!"));
            }
            return getFormMAV(product);
        } else {
            try {
                String uploadedFile = fileService.store(file);
                LOG.info("File received {}", uploadedFile);
                product.setImagePath(uploadedFile);
                //product.setTimestamp(LocalDateTime.now());
                productService.save(product);

                return new ModelAndView ("redirect:/");

            } catch (IOException | FileServiceException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LOG.error("Error during file store", e);

                bindingResult.addError(new FieldError("product",
                        "imagePath",
                        "Problem z wysylka pliku"));

                return getFormMAV(product);
            }
        }
    }
}


You have overcomplicated the problem.  This isn't really an AWS/S3 problem at all. Focus on getting the Android app to send the file to the Spring Boot server. Once you have that completed, the Spring Boot server can save the file locally, or send it to S3 or whatever. The Android app should not know or care at all that the file is ultimately stored on AWS.

@MarkB Yeah, from Android app side no difference - just send data to spring app server

Temporarily solved (on the android app side):
        if (views.get("shareVideo").equals("true")){
            views.put("shareVideo", "false");
            System.out.println("sharing...");
            String url = "http://10.0.2.2:9089/add/";
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            File file = new File(play.arr.androidLauncher.outputDirectory, "1.jpg");
            RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
            try {
                params.put("file", file);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                //TODO: Handle error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //TODO: Reaming body with id "property". prepareJson converts property class to Json string. Replace this with with your own method
            client.post(play.arr.androidLauncher.getContext(), url, params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                    System.out.print("Failed..");
                }
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                    System.out.print("Success..");
                }
                @Override
                public boolean getUseSynchronousMode() {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void setUseSynchronousMode(boolean useSynchronousMode) {
                }
            });
        }

